# Can hypnotherapy help focus/productivity

Tags: hypnotism

I've always been a bit intrigued by hypnotherapy. I'd like to be more productive and more focused. I find in short bursts I can be extremely focused and get a lot done and other times I can find it hard to stop my mind from wandering and waste time.

My question is, should I consider hypnotherapy to try help me become more focused, has anyone tried this before with positive or no results?

Comment: Any number of claims that this is possible, but all from marketers as best I can tell. The title seems legit as to whether it can help, but the question text itself seems more like a request for help.

Comment: The question must be about more precise claims. Moreover, this question “has anyone tried this before with positive or no results?” bothers me. If I tell you it helped me, will you be convinced? A personal experience is not a proof or an evidence of something. Maybe you should ask for scientific studies about hypnosis and its effects on focus.

Comment: please cite a claim for the title

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. In particular, do you mean focus *during* hypnosis, or as a permanent treatment?

Comment: I found a quote on the use of hypnosis for memory where they claim that "Hypnosis increases productivity, but most of the new information is in error". 
http://ruccs.rutgers.edu/faculty/pylyshyn/TreismanReadings/09-Perry-Hypnosis.pdf

Comment: https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/binaural-beats-for-productivity